# Specializing function templates in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I am familiar with class specialization but came across this piece of code which I believe is function specialization

```
A:
template <bool include_negatives>
int average(int* array, int len) {
....
}
```

I could rewrite the above as this `C` . I know that I am specializing a class so I need to provide B. My question is what is happening in A. Why does that not need a generic type since its being specialized.

```
B:
template<typename t>
int average(){

}

C:
template<>
int average<bool>(){
  ...
}
```

My question is why does the

Comment: *"My question is why does the"*. Seems unfinished question... There are 2 kinds of person, those who can extrapolate.

Comment: Doesn't look like a specialization. Just a function template.

Comment: Not answering the question,  but if you have a bool template, you have to call them as `average<true>(  )`  and `average<false>(  )` That could just as well be two non-template functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include_negative` is a [non type template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) using the integral type `bool`.

There is no specialization in this case. The template parameter has a fixed type that serves as a placeholder for a `constexpr` value. In the aforementioned link you'll see that **"A non-type template parameter must have a structural type, which is one of the following types (optionally cv-qualified, the qualifiers are ignored):"**

> - lvalue reference type (to object or to function);
> - an integral type;
> - a pointer type (to object or to function);
> - a pointer to member type (to member object or to member function);
> - an enumeration type;
> - std::nullptr_t;
> - a floating-point type;
> - a literal class type (...)